# How to access the boundary in Quest 2?

Tags: oculus, oculusquest

I'm developing a simulation in the Oculus/Meta Quest 2 and would like to access the boundary coordinates. In the past, there was a GetGeometry option but it appears to have been deprecated. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.